# Hebrew became gibberish

Tags: sql-server, hebrew

I have an iPhone simulator app as client and **WCF-REST**, json encoded service running on **IIS 7.0 server**.

I'm trying to send some hebrew characters to the service as parameter and the server return error code `400 - Bad Request`. When I'm sending an English string the server processes the string as it should.

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."* - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Remove the `sql-server` tab from your question unless you have a reason to suspect the database you are using is related to the problem. It doesn't seem to be relevant from the information provided.